# Setting up local repository in QGIS 3.1

Tags: qgis-3, xml, repository

I'm trying to create a local repository to make easier the distribution of plugins within my company.

Although eveything goes smoothly in QGIS 2.14, it seems I can't repeat the same process with QGIS 3.1 !

The structure of my plugins.xml file looks as follows:

1. First case: downloading a plugin from gitlab

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
 <pyqgis_plugin name="plugin_name" version="1.0">
     <description>description here</description>
     <qgis_minimum_version>3.0</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>plugin_name.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Wanderzen</author_name>
     <download_url>https://gitlab.com/username/plugin_v1/-/blob/master/plugin_name.zip</download_url>
 </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

2. Second case: downloading a plugin from a network drive

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
 <pyqgis_plugin name="plugin_name" version="1.0">
     <description>description here</description>
     <qgis_minimum_version>3.0</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>plugin_name.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Wanderzen</author_name>
     <download_url>S:\Users\Wanderzen\shared_folder\plugin_name.zip</download_url>
 </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

In both cases the connection to the repository is successful but when I go to the "uninstalled plugins" tab and I click on the plugin I want to install I get those errors:

- with Gitlab: `Can't install the plugin: failure in the unzipping of the plugin. The plugin may be corrupted or missing in the repository (Échec de l'installation: Échec de la décompression de l'extension. Soit elle est corrompue, soit elle est manquante sur le dépôt)`
- with the local directory:`Can't install the plugin: unknown "s" protocol (Échec de l'installation: Le protocole "s" est inconnu)`

Has someone faced the same problem ?!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have found the solution for the second case :

I had well added the prefix `file:`in the url poiting to my plugin.xml (see picture below) ...
[image]

... but I had forgotten to add the same prefix in the "download_url" of my plugin.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<plugins>
 <pyqgis_plugin name="plugin_name" version="1.0">
     <description>description here</description>
     <qgis_minimum_version>3.0</qgis_minimum_version>
     <file_name>plugin_name.zip</file_name>
     <author_name>Wanderzen</author_name>
     <download_url>file:S:/path_to_my_network_drive/plugin_name.zip</download_url>
 </pyqgis_plugin>
</plugins>
```

Hope it helps ! :)

NB: I haven't found a solution with Gitlab yet though !